# How to read test data from excel sheet and provide into webpage and mark test case as pass or fail accordigly in selenium web script using POI

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

The scenario that I am trying to achieve is pass the data from excel sheet into my web page and run the test and accordingly mark test case as pass or fail in the same excel sheet.
Till now I have successfully passed the data from excel sheet into wen page but failed to mark testcase pass/fail. I am using selenium with JAVA and POI. My excel sheet has 3 columns and I want fourth column with results a pass or Fail.In order to test if  a test is pass or fail I will compare if the data gets added successfully its pass else fail (which I can do) but i m not able to write into my excel sheet as pass or fail.
My script is

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 400);
FileInputStream IPLinkProFile = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Selenium\\Input_Data\\IPLProImport.xlsx"));
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(IPLProFile);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("IPLPro");
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
while (rowIterator.hasNext())
    {
        String projectName = null;
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("ctl00_InsertButton")));
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00InsertButton")).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("ctl00_pname1")));
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_Arrow")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form1']//div/ul/li[2]")).click();
        Iterator <Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext())
        {

            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            if(cell.getColumnIndex()==0)
            {
                driver.findElement (By.id("ctl00_pname1")).clear();
                driver.findElement (By.id("ctl00_pname1")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
            }else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==1)
            {
                driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_gvhost1")).clear();
                driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_gvhost1")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
            }else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==2)
            {
                driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_username1")).clear();
                driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_username1")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
            }


            else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==3)
            {
                driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_gcpass1")).clear();
                driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_gcpass1")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
            }
            else
            {
                break; 
            }

        }
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_btnUpdateImport")).click();
        Thread.sleep(50000);
        driver.switchTo().frame("ImportTest");
        driver.findElement(By.id("form1"));
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnClose")).click();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think we can achieve it but use TestNG framework, where after running all test cases it will automatically generate reports. Through TestNG you can run all the test cases at a time  and through it you can only run failed test cases in later stages

Comment: I am trying to understand which part of the scenario we cannot achieve. Setting the testcase a pass or fail back to excel sheet? or something else? If I need to write result into another excel sheet I am fine with it. I know that we can write back the data into excel sheet using POI.